# Garbage value on reading from a file using getline

Tags: c++, getline

I am writing a small program to just get the lines from a srt file in a specific format. However I am getting a garbage value in the very first (and only that) read I do using getline. Can someone point out why am I getting this abnormal behaviour?

```
//Small program to get the text from the srt files.

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

void srtToTranscript(ifstream* iFile, ofstream *oFile);

int main(){
std::string file_name;
std::string transcript;

cout << "Enter srt file name (without extension)";
cin >> file_name;

ifstream iFile;
ofstream oFile;

iFile.clear();

iFile.open("data\\" + file_name+".srt");
oFile.open("data\\" + file_name + "_result.txt");
srtToTranscript(&iFile,&oFile);
cout << "Conversion done. Check in the same folder";
cout << "Press a key to exit... ";
while (!_kbhit());
char dummy = _getch();
return 0;
}

void srtToTranscript(ifstream* iFile, ofstream* oFile)
{
        int i = 1;
        std:string line;
        for (; getline(*iFile, line);)  
        {
            cout << line << endl;
            cout << to_string(i) << endl;

            if (line.compare(to_string(i)) == 0){
                getline(*iFile, line);
                i++;
                continue;
            }

            *oFile << line + ",\n";
        }
        oFile->close();
}
```

appended is a sample of the file I am reading from:

> 1
>
> 00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:12,000
>
> Translator: Thu-Huong Ha
>
> 2
>
> 00:00:12,038 --> 00:00:15,012
>
> Over the last two decades, India has become

Comment: As a side note: Why are you passing the arguments of `srtToTranscript` as pointers? What if someone passes a null pointer?

Comment: I was just trying out something. Do not consider this as production level code. You think it is the pointers causing the problem?

Comment: What output is written to `cout`, and what output would you expect?

Comment: I am not writing anything to cout. Everything is written on a file.

Comment: The code you show definitely writes to `cout`, for debugging reasons I guess. Knowing that output, as well as what you write to the file, could help us understand what's going on. You might also want run in a debugger, and step through the code in the function line by line.

Comment: @zenith I double-checked by doing away with the function (and hence the pointers) and reading/writing in main itself. I still have the exact same issue.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg My bad. It simply writes each line it is reading from the file and the value of the counter 'i'. 
I did use the debugger and I see that the string line has some garbage value for the first getline (it is shows "ï»¿1" when it should be "1"). Thereafter everything is read correctly (i.e. line has the same value as is there in the input file).

Comment: The "garbage values" you are seeing is the [UTF-8 byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8). How was the file created? You might want to check out the settings of your editor.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The Byte order mark comment was spot. my issue is resolved. Would you like to add this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `ifile` is not being opened successfully.

I'm seeing `#include <conio.h>` in your include list so I assume that you are working on Visual Studio? If you have use the default directory structure when setting up Visual Studio, then say that you have a project named: "Foo" Your .srt file needs to go here:

> .../Documents/Visual Studio 20##/Projects/Foo/Foo/data/Foo.srt

When I correctly placed the file there and at the prompt I entered:

> Foo

I got this output in: ".../Documents/Visual Studio 20##/Projects/Foo/Foo/data/Foo_result.txt":

> 00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:12,000,
>   ,
>   Translator: Thu-Huong Ha,
>   ,
>   00:00:12,038 --> 00:00:15,012,
>   ,
>   Over the last two decades, India has become,

One thing I'd make sure of is that your `line` declaration in `srtToTranscript` is defined:

```
string line
```

Not:

```
std:string line
```

Comment: The problem is solved by saving my file without the BOM mark as JoachimPileborg pointed out in the comments. T\